# C# Convert String CONTENTS to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

My string contains the bytes (e.g 0x27), basically what I need to do is convert that string array which contains the byte data to a `byte` data type, so then I can encode it in `UTF8`, so it displays meaningful info.

1 string array contains:

> 0x37, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x33, 0x39, 0x37, 0x32,0x2d, 0x30, 0x31

I need that converted to a byte array, is that possible?

My code is:

```
        string strData;
        string strRaw;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.InnerXml = Data;
        XmlElement xmlDocElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        strData = xmlDocElement.GetAttribute("datalabel").ToString();
        strRaw = xmlDocElement.GetAttribute("rawdata").ToString();

        string[] arrData = strData.Split(' ');
        string[] arrRaw = strRaw.Split(' ');
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean the string contains text like '0x23 ' or the chars in the string have the value of 23 hex etc?

Comment: Text is 0x23, so like for example: string str = "0x23"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To say the 'string contains the bytes' could be interpreted in a few ways. You can extract a string into bytes in a number of ways. Converting a string directly into bytes based on UTF8 encoding:

```
var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
```

There are of course similar methods for other encodings.

**Ignore the above**

Your comment changes the way the question reads quite a bit!  If your strings are just hex (i.e. the bytes are not encoded into the string) just convert from hex to integers.  Something like....

```
var b = Convert.ToUInt32(str.Substring(2), 16)

// For an array
var bytes = new byte[arrData.Length];
for(var i = 0; i < arrData.Length; i++) {
   bytes[i] = (byte)Convert.ToUInt32(arrData[i].Substring(2), 16);
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is, the bytes are stored in an array, and GetBytes does not accept a string array.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question - your comment - str = "0x23" changes this entirely.  All you want to do is parse these strings as hex.  var b = Convert.ToUInt32(str.Substring(2), 16)

Comment: Ok so how would I be able to do this with a string array?

Comment: You would loop over the array and do this for every element.  You could get fancy and then write that as LINQ or something - but at the end of the day it's a loop.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to point out, that I need it as a byte array. so from a string array to a byte array, so then I can encode it in UTF8.

Comment: I've knocked up an example of a loop.. you can do this in one line with LINQ but the example code demonstrates the algorithm in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, I will have to read up on LINQ, as I have not used it before.

Answer (score 1):

If you have each byte in a char and just want to convert it to a byte array without using an encoding, use;

```
string blip = "\x4A\x62";
byte[] blop = (from ch in blip select (byte)ch).ToArray();
```

If you want to convert it using UTF8 encoding right away, use

```
string blip = "\x4A\x62";
var blop = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blip);
```

Answer (score 1):

given your string is "0x37, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x33, 0x39, 0x37, 0x32,0x2d, 0x30, 0x31" or similar you can get the byte values like this;

```
string input = "0x37, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x33, 0x39, 0x37, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x30, 0x31";

string[] bytes = input.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

byte[] values = new byte[bytes.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    values[i] = byte.Parse(bytes[i].Substring(2,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", values[i]));
}
```

once you have them you need to feed them into an apropriate Encoder/Decoder to get the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(str);
```